# Rails - How do i update a records value in a join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a join model in a HABTM relationship with a through association (details below).  I 'm trying to find a record....find the value of that records attribute...change the value and update the record but am having a hard time doing it.

The model setup is this>>

User.rb

```
 has_many :choices
 has_many :interests, :through => :choices
```

Interest.rb

```
 has_many :choices
 has_many :users, :through => :choices
```

Choice.rb

```
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :interest
```

and Choice has the user_id, interest_id, score as fields.

And I find the ?object? like so >>

```
@choice = Choice.where(:user_id => @user.id, :interest_id => interest.id)
```

So the model Choice has an attribute called :score.  How do I find the value of the score column....and +1/-1 it and then resave?

I tried

```
 @choice.score = @choice.score + 1 
 @choice.update_attributes(params[:choice])
 flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated choices value."
```

but I get "undefined method score"......What did i miss?

Comment: Check! May be you are getting array of @choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use `.first` to run the actual query and return a result:

```
@choice = Choice.where(:user_id => @user.id, :interest_id => interest.id).first
```

... otherwise `@choice` only holds an Active Relation object... it hasn't executed the query yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your query will return a collection of choices so you need specify .first to get hold of the actual model to update. And before you update, always check to see if you actually got hold of any object so you don't try to update nil :)

Additionally, if you only want to increase or decrease a field then you can use the methods .increment! or .decrement! which will update to database immediately.

```
@choice.increment!(:score)
```

Because in your case, if params[:choice] contains a score value, it will overwrite the value you assigned previously.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the @user object, so use that:

@choice = @user.choices.find_by_interest_id(interest.id)